# How to get try function to work?

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I want my function (named try) to make sure that:

1. cell is not in cells
2. the coordinates of cell are between 0 and maze-size 1
3. cell touches exactly one Cell in cells.

**Definitions:**

```
(define maze-size 15)
(define-struct Cell (x y))

(define (random-element a-list)
(list-ref a-list (random (length a-list))))

(define (random-adjacent cell)
(let ((neighbors (adjacents cell)))
(list-ref neighbors (random (length neighbors)))))


(define (count-in cell cells)
(cond
[(member? cell cells) 1]
[else 0]))

(define (touches cell cells)
(+
(count-in (make-Cell (Cell-x cell) (+ (Cell-y cell) 1)) cells)
(count-in (make-Cell (Cell-x cell) (+ (Cell-y cell) -1)) cells)
(count-in (make-Cell (+ (Cell-x cell) -1) (Cell-y cell)) cells)
(count-in (make-Cell (+ (Cell-x cell) 1) (Cell-y cell)) cells)))
```

**Here is what I have:**

```
(define (try cell cells)
(cond [(=? 1(touches cell cells)) (member? cell cells) (=? 1(cell-post))]
[(zero? (random (sqr maze-size))) cells]
[else (extend cells)]))
```

and yes I know the syntax is wrong in the first condition, my cond statements aren't strong.

**What is the syntax needed in this case?**

Keep in mind it should also work for this code:

```
(define (extend cells)
(try (random-adjacent cells) cells))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but what you describe would be expressed as

```scm
(define (try cell cells)
  (and (not (member? cell cells))
       (<= 0 (Cell-x cell) maze-size)
       (<= 0 (Cell-y cell) maze-size)
       (= 1 (touches cell cells))))
```